# Can I change a Vim setting persistently using a shortcut?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

Can I change a Vim setting **persistently** using a shortcut?

Hypothetical Example:

```
nnoremap <script> <F7> :call ChangeConfig()<cr>
function! ChangeConfig()
     set virtualedit=all
endfunction
```

If yes, I could save my own settings?

Hypothetical Example:

```
nnoremap <script> <F8> :call ChangeConfig()<cr>
function! ChangeConfig()
     set mysetting="myvalue"
endfunction
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could... But it would probably involve editing a config file (.vimrc or something sourced on load) programically. Since that is the only way settings persist between sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist option values beyond the current Vim session, the corresponding `:set` commands have to be written to some config file.

#### global persistence

Vim actually provides an option to persist *all* current options (and more, like opened files), called **sessions**. What gets persisted is controlled by `'sessionoptions'` (it needs to contain `options`). The persistence is controlled by `:mksession` and `:source`; you can automate those via `:autocmds`.

#### selected persistence

If you only want to persist certain options, you have to do this on your own. You could write / update a section of your `~/.vimrc`, but it's easier to use a separate plugin file:

```
nnoremap <script> <F7> :call ChangeConfig()<cr>
function! ChangeConfig()
    set virtualedit=all
    call writefile(['set virtualedit=all', '" more options here'], expand('~/.vim/plugin/persisted_options.vim'))
endfunction
```

Comment: Ingo Karkat, another perfect answer! I'm building a script (GPL) to Vim. I'd be happy to show you soon! Thanks and take your points!